# NSInvocation error in class which doesn't exist anymore

Tags: iphone, ios, class, core-data

I had a class named "Object", changed the name to TheObject (everywhere in my project) cause I thought it would cause problems. (TheObject is a CoreData generated class)

Now i get this error:

```
2012-09-21 14:19:45.794 Choose3[1348:fb03] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x191f500 of class 'Object' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2012-09-21 14:19:45.794 Choose3[1348:fb03] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x191f500 of class 'Object' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

Why does Xcode still think I have a class named Object while I haven't ?

Comment: perhaps you didn't get rid of it "everywhere"? Interface builder files? Maybe try grepping the project directory to see if it shows up anywhere

Comment: I've looked in finder and there's no class anymore named Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the entity in the model was changed but the class of the entity was still Object, and not TheObject.